# What are the GUI libraries used by Unity3d and other software that doesn't look like traditional applications?

Tags: user-interface

I have been dealing with GTK & QT on linux, Windows forms on windows and some others like Tk, Wx. But I can see a lot of GUIs that don't look like traditional applications like unity 3d, some Adobe applications, 3ds max etc..
Are they using special libraries ? or there is a way for advanced theming of the above libraries ? Or are they just creating their own libraries ? How do they create them ?

Answer (score 1):

Well usually they make their own libraries

Some applications ( exp : `Blender`  ( that has a really good GUI )) use there own libraries .

`Blender` implements its whole GUI using `OpenGL` so `Unity` , `3DsMax` should be similar

*By ( that has a really good GUI ) I mean it looks good

*3 years but I Just saw the question ;)

Comment: Some similar themed software is using Qt, like Spotify, Skype, Nuke and CATIA. The new Qt Quick javascript-inspired declarative language is very useful for creating custom UI's

Answer (score 1):

I believe Unity uses Dear ImGui for the their UI, especially with the new UI documents system, it's quite impressive how much stuff you can do with it, you can look for some tutorials about it and if you have heard of Hazel engine (from The Cherno channel in You Tube) it uses ImGui to render all the UI, so try going it a look, it might suit you.

Dear ImGui: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYsOo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the libraries that are independent will do a lot from scratch. Eg. use Cairo directly in building their engine so that they can do display and capture input from the users as well. A lot of the widgets they have for the GUI are done from basic bottom up principles. The new non-server standalone apps can use frameworks like Electron (which desktop apps like Skype now use) rely on HTML/CSS/Javascript so that the primitive widgets are the standard browser elements of a webpage navigation in an application form.